# Lenovo S850 crashes randomly!

Tags: crashes, lenovo

Lenovo crashed randomly thrice this week. The screen each time just went black and the phone would not turn back on afterwards when power button was pressed and held; however, after a few hours it would turn on by **itself**. When the phone is in a such a *"blackout"* (sorry for a lack of a better word) and the power button is pressed and held the screen flashes for a short second but then  becomes black again. Before it crashes, the phone does not freeze or get stuck, i.e the phone is running fine before it just blacks out. The phone runs quite smoothly otherwise. RAM isn't the problem as well.

I don't know if this is related or not but the apps being used when the crash occurred were youtube and two gaming apps, including Cheating Tom.

What should I do? Should the phone be taken to an expert or can I do something to fix it myself?

Comment: I'd first try to leave those apps alone, especially the games, and see if the issue persists. If after a week it did not repeat, one of those games is likely to be the culprit.

Comment: @Izzy  and if it does persist? I did delete those games  were right after the incidents happened though. The latest crash came while using youtube.

Comment: Hard to say. Can you reproduce the crash (i.e. do you know steps that force it to happen)? Most "service lines" would now insist on a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info); but if you can reproduce it using the Youtube app (which came pre-installed with your device), you could try doing the very same from [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) first and see if it crashes as well. If so, a factory-reset might be needed.

Comment: @Izzy  There are no particular steps that make it crash; each time they're unique. This time i used youtube and did the same things as before, but it did not crash. I'm not an android expert at all but I don't think its really related to a specific app. I think maybe there's something wrong in the software itself

Comment: Sara, there are possibilities to check what's going on (see e.g. our [logging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info)). If you think you can go that path, it might help you figure. If that looks too complex for you, I'm afraid apart from literally handing your device to an "expert", all that's left is already mentioned factory-reset.

Comment: @Izzy oh well I'll just try factory reset then. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime. Don't forget to let us know the outcome. If it solved your issue (which I expect it to do), you can also [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) ;) Good luck!